# C# .NET - ctrl-c keyup not triggered when ctrl is released first

Tags: c#, .net, copy-paste

I have a DataGridView that catches the KeyUp event. I use it to
capture a keyboard copy(ctrl-c) and then perform my own formatting on
the copied text. Everything works as it should when I release the 'C'
key first, but if I release 'ctrl' first while still holding 'C', it
doesn't trigger the event. Below is the code for the event. I'm
already handling it on a copy context menu item but I know i'll have
users using the keyboard shortcuts and I'd prefer to have everything
work as expected. Any ideas are appreciated.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Key up event handler
  /// </summary>
  void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control == true )
        {
            CopyToClipboard(dgDS408Parameter.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());               
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that is the intended keyboard behaviour.

Comment: I think your code is conceptually wrong. I think there are specialized hotkey/shortcut functionalities, instead of hacking it into key handlers.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool CtrlPressed=false;

void Control_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && ctrlPressed == true )
    {
        CopyToClipboard(dgDS408Parameter.CurrentCell.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());                           
    }
    CtrlPressed=false;
}   

void Control_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{          
    if (e.Control == true )
    {
        CtrlPressed=true;
    }
}
```

I wrote it on my mind, not tested, but the idea is like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is logical error in you code you write

```
e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control == true
```

It means "C" and "Cnt" both key have to be in pressed stat when Any key fire keyUp event.

So what happens here is when you press Cnt + C its ok but when you release 'ctrl' first the condition is wrong

```
e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control == true
```

That's why your data is not copied in clip board

Answer (score 0):

Why use the key-up event? All other programs do the same thing on key-down. Change your event from `KeyUp` to `KeyDown` and everything will be fine.